# JSON Object Error in JAVA

Tags: java, playframework, fbconnect

Hey I am following the fbconnect module tutorial [here](http://www.playframework.org/modules/fbconnect-0.4/home) to implement login with Facebook functionality

I have this action in my User Model

```
public static void facebookOAuthCallback(JsonObject data){
 String email = data.get("email").getAsString();
 User user = findByEmail(email);
if(user == null){
    user = new User();
    user.email = email;
    user.insert();
}
Session.current().put("user", user.email);
}
```

I get this error. Do I need to import something?
**The file /app/models/User.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : JsonObject cannot be resolved to a type**

Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: You need to import JsonObject class. I think, http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/json/JsonObject.html. Cross check it.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman i added import com.google.gson.JsonObject; in my model but now I am getting this error The method findByEmail(String) is undefined for the type User

Comment: I think you need to add required jar in your java project. I found documentation here http://restfb.com/javadoc/ . There is User class in it.

Comment: @JProgrammer i get this error now The file /app/models/User.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Session cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you have a whole lot of imports missing. Easiest solution would be to use an IDE like IntelliJ, that has the playframework source files (/framework/src).

If you can't do this, then try looking up each issue you have, and searching for the related imports that you would need.

From your last comment, `Session` is actually an inner class of Http, so you need to import `play.mvc.Http`.

Comment: I imported play.mvc.Scope in my user model and in action I want to create a new session like 
Session session = Scope.Session.current(); 
session.put("user", user.email);
bu I get the error Session cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: in your controller, you will already have a session. Just use `session`, all lower case. You don't need to create a new one. Also, the Session class is an inner class of Http, not Scope (well its both, but the Http one is the one you want)

Comment: Can you give me an example? what to import in my model